# What actually IS the functionality of the "lock user" function on Ubuntu Landscape?

Tags: ssh, juju, landscape

I'm testing out Ubuntu Landscape, but the only client I have available to me is only accessible via SSH. I've tried locking the user on it as described in the documentation, but when that's finished I can still SSH into the user just fine. I noticed the `sudo` command doesn't work on the "locked" user, however.

My questions are, what is the scope on the Landscape user lock, what does it look like when a locked user tries to log in, and is there a way to make it so that the lock targets SSH as well besides simply disabling SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually nothing specific to landscape there.

In short, locked account are users for which the password entry starts with a "!", thus disabling password access (see `man passwd` on your system for more details). It generally doesn't look different from a failed password attempt.

ssh may still allow key based authentication for locked users depending on its configuration. `UsePAM yes` is known to have that effect, and is enabled by default on Ubuntu.

Here are a couple ways you can achieve user locking:

- set `UsePAM no` in sshd_config
- disable PubkeyAuthentication
- not use locking mechanism but rather set expiration date on the user
- set the shell of the user to `/usr/sbin/nologin`
- there are probably other settings related to PAM you can use, but I'm not familiar enough with them